# Sending data from AngularJS to PHP for IF-statement in PHP with perhaps in proper syntax?

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to send data from `AngularJS` to `PHP`.

I am sending the data from the `controller.js` of `AngularJS`.
I am receiving the data through `PHP`. The data comes well for others variables.

However, I don't know which part is the problem.

My goal is to have the `PHP` recognize `$step_number` and run through the IF-statement in `PHP`, but even though I send wrong data, it works!

Which means,
if the `$step_number` in `PHP` is `'2'`, then the IF-statement in `PHP` should not work as shown in below. But, it runs!

I thought this was the proper way to write the code as other data are being passed to `PHP`.

<kbd>Controller.js</kbd>

```
$http.post("../crud/projects_update.php",{
    step_number : '1', // This one, I am trying to send, but I don't know whether this is not being sent or the problem is occurred in PHP.
    project_id : $scope.project_data.project_id // This works in the PHP. It is well sent.
    project_title : $scope.project_data.project_title
}
```

<kbd>PHP</kbd>

```
require_once 'connect.php';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$step_number = $data->step_number; // This should be received from AngularJS and if the $step_number is not matched in the IF-statement, then the function in { } should not work.

if ($step_number = '1'){
    $project_id = $data->project_id;
    $project_title = $data->project_title;
    $conn->query("UPDATE `projects` SET
    `project_title` = '$project_title',WHERE `project_id` = $project_id") or die(mysqli_error());   
}
```

Comment: problem seems in php as `if ($step_number = '1'){` is assignment not comparison. so change it to `if ($step_number == 1){`  and change `step_number : '1',` to `step_number : 1,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things need to change:-

1.Change `step_number : '1',` to `step_number : 1,`

2.Change

```
if ($step_number = '1'){ //this is assignment not comparison
```

to:-

```
if ($step_number == 1){ // now it's comparison
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! It worked! Hope this helps the others as well! :)